# How to solve Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR error while running a database app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I was learning sqlite database using android. Made an app. Android studio doesn't show any error . But while running it , It shows Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR error when i click on insert button.

So how to solve it?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.buckydroid.database;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public EditText name;
   public EditText age;
   public  EditText gender;
    public Button button;
    public Button button2;


database db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new database(this);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        gender = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        insertworks();
        Showdata();

    }
    public void insertworks(){
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      boolean result =  db.add_data(name.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString(),gender.getText().toString());
                        if(result){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
        );
    }
    public void Showdata(){
        button2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor data = db.all_data();
                        if(data.getCount()==0){
showMessage("Error","No Data Found");
                        }
                        else{
                            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                            while (data.moveToNext())
                            buffer.append("Id = "+data.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Name = "+data.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Age = "+data.getString(2)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Gender = "+data.getString(3)+"\n"+"\n");
                            showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());

                        }


                    }

                }
        );

    }
    public void showMessage(String title,String Message){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("title");
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

database.java

```
package com.buckydroid.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by BuckyDroidz on 20-08-2016.
 */
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "BuckyDroid";
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "Students";
    public static String COL1 = "ID";
    public static String COL2 = "NAME";
    public static String COL3 = "AGE";
    public static String COL4 = "GENDER";


    public database(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+COL1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COL2+" TEXT, "+COL3+" TEXT, "+COL4+" TEXT "+");");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean add_data(String name, String age, String gender) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,age);
        contentValues.put(COL4,gender);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

        return false;
    }
    public Cursor all_data(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor dota = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return dota;

    }
}
```

Error Log :

```
08-20 12:24:14.626 6241-6254/com.buckydroid.database I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3315(133KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2011KB/3MB, paused 661us total 178.136ms
08-20 12:24:24.581 6241-6249/com.buckydroid.database W/art: Suspending all threads took: 157.482ms
08-20 12:24:33.105 6241-6527/com.buckydroid.database W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-20 12:24:33.105 6241-6527/com.buckydroid.database W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3928680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```